# Deserialization issue only in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi, deserialization

I typically build a jar and deploy said jar with ant, however I need to debug an issue so I dropped the code into eclipse and tried to run the `main` class (with all the same parameters as I typically try to run the jar with).

However, I am getting this issue and I've been banging my head against a wall for awhile. I tried to add `private static final serialVersionUID` to the 466..., I also tried setting it to 1L, and adding the annotation to ignore the warning.

However it keeps throwing the `InvalidClassException`.

Is there anyway to get Eclipse to act more like doing the `java -jar myjar.jar` that ant builds. Also is there any reason why this is specifically happening here? (It's also the same JVM I'm using to run the jar with).

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.blah.MyClass local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 46644259037142, local class serialVersionUID = -175274031382959
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your jar has a different version of the class in it. Make sure the two classes match (and that it's the same version that this data was serialized with).

This is one reason why some people don't like Java serialization ;)

Answer (score 1):

Even slightly changing a serializable class will change the [SUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) unless you explicitly specify the same version. If this class is used to deserialize a persisted object created with an older version, you get the error you are seeing.

Its not clear how you are trying to serialize/deserialize the object, but I'm guessing its a RMI client-server class version problem. Is the class deployed for both client & server?

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse compiler does not generate the same serialVersionUIDs as javac, see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_does_the_Eclipse_compiler_create_a_different_serialVersionUID_from_javac?). If you want interoperability betwwen javac and the eclipse compiler, define

```
    public static final long serialVersionUID = ...;
```

in all your serializable classes, them it will work.